# How to insert RecycleView between Viewpager and its Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have ViewPager with 3 pages of PageFragments.

I want to extend it to have 3 parents pages which are not swipable. In every pages there is RecyclerView with PageFragments so I can swipe through fragment but not change the parent page.

Current state shown below.

Parent StatsFragment :

```
private PageFragment pageOne;
private PageFragment pageTwo;
private PageFragment pageThree;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("7 days"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1 month"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1 year"));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final CustomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager) layout.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    pageOne = PageFragment.newInstance(0);
    pageTwo = PageFragment.newInstance(1);
    pageThree = PageFragment.newInstance(2);
    adapter.addFragment(pageOne,"7 days");
    adapter.addFragment(pageTwo,"1 month");
    adapter.addFragment(pageThree,"1 year");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
    return layout;
}
```

TabFragment:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
private int pageNumber;
public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("page_number", page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return (fragment);
}

public PageFragment(){}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt("page_number");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
    processChanges(layout, pageNumber);
    return (layout);
}

public void processChanges(View tabView, int tabNum)
{
    int d =7;
    int m =0;
    int y =0;
    MMDatabaseHelper sloh = MMDatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity());

    if (tabNum == 1)
    {
        d =0;
        m =1;
        y =0;
    }
    else if (tabNum == 2)
    {
        d =0;
        m =0;
        y =1;
    }
    createGraph(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);
    setBalances(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);
    setListValues(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);
}

private void setListValues(View tabView, int d, int m, int y,MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    // Creating incomes list
    ListView incomeListView = (ListView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.listViewIncomeStats);
    Cursor incomeRecords = sloh.getRecordsInRange(">",d,m,y);
    RecordsDbToStatsAdapter incomeAdapter = new RecordsDbToStatsAdapter(this.getContext(), incomeRecords, 0);
    incomeListView.setAdapter(incomeAdapter);

    // Creating expenses list
    ListView expensesListView = (ListView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.listViewExpences);
    Cursor expensesRecords = sloh.getRecordsInRange("<",d,m,y);
    RecordsDbToStatsAdapter expensesAdapter = new RecordsDbToStatsAdapter(this.getContext(), expensesRecords, 0);
    expensesListView.setAdapter(expensesAdapter);
}


private Date numbersToDate(int daysBack, int monthsBack, int yearsBack)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, daysBack *(-1));
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthsBack *(-1));
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, yearsBack *(-1));
    return  cal.getTime();
}

private void setBalances(View tabView, int d, int m, int y, MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    //Fetching Values of incomes and expenses and balances
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    TextView startBal = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.startBalance);
    BigDecimal startValue = new BigDecimal(sloh.getStartingBal(numbersToDate(d,m,y)).toString());
    startBal.setText(String.valueOf(startValue.setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView endBal = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.endBalance);
    BigDecimal endValue = new BigDecimal(sloh.getEndingBal().toString());
    endBal.setText(String.valueOf(endValue.setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView incSum = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.incomeSumStats);
    Integer helpInc = sloh.getSumRecordsInRange(">",d,m,y);
    BigDecimal incValue = new BigDecimal(helpInc.toString());
    incSum.setText(String.valueOf(incValue.setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView expSum = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.expenseSumStats);
    Integer helpExp = sloh.getSumRecordsInRange("<",d,m,y);
    BigDecimal expValue = new BigDecimal(helpExp.toString());
    expSum.setText(String.valueOf(expValue.setScale(2).doubleValue()));
}

private void createGraph(View tabView, int d, int m, int y, MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    // Graph rendering section
    // Cursor graphCursor = sloh.getRecordsInRange(null,d,m,y);
    // graphCursor.moveToFirst();
    int days=0;
    if (d == 7) { days = d;}
    if (m == 1) { days = 28;}
    if (y == 1) { days = 365;}

    ArrayList numList = new ArrayList();
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] { });

    Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
    day.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    day.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    day.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    for(int i=days; i>0;i--) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-i);
        day.setTime(cal.getTime());
        Log.i("TIME",cal.getTime().toString());
        numList.add(sloh.getCurrentBalanceForOneDay(cal.getTime()));
        series.appendData(new DataPoint(day.getTime(),sloh.getCurrentBalanceForOneDay(cal.getTime())),true,days);
    }

    Log.i("Pole", numList.toString());

    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(getActivity()));
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(4); // only 4 because of the space

    graph.addSeries(series);
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> mTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    mTitles.add(title);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return (mFragments.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (mFragments.size());
}

@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return (mTitles.get(position));
}
}
@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
return (mTitles.get(position));
}
}
```

Comment: So you want a one view pager non swipable wih three pages. In each pages you want a recycler view that display three other pages swipable. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. I have in tabs set timerange and according to chosen timerange i wanna swipe through data. 
Example: i choose 7 days as timerange. Than in recycleview i wanna swipe in 7 days range in its childs

Comment: Do you want to have a scroll effect or really a swipe effect when changing the pages ? And is there a maximum for the timerange ?

Comment: swipe effect would be much better but this is already out of my knowledge. Timerange is 1 year. I have there a logic for TabFragments now to take right data. Currently there is Viewpager with ViewPagerAdapter that tstores this TabFragments. Now i need to rework it so in Viewpager with its adapter will be something that stores those TabFragments.

Comment: Maybe the RecyclerView is not what you want actually. Can you post your xml ?